Why is the Darboux integral referred to as the Riemann integral in Rudin?
I've been taking a real analysis class, and in the course and the problem sets we differentiated between the Riemann and Darboux integrals (I know that the two are equal, but sometimes we'd be asked to solve an integral using the Riemann integral, and sometimes using the Darboux integral). Now I'm studying for the final exam using Rudin's International series in pure and applied mathematics, and they give a definition of the Riemann integral that seems equivalent to the definition of the Darboux integral that we saw in class (rather than the definition we learned of the Riemann integral, which was done in terms of endpoints of the intervals). Am I missing anything, or is this actually a definition of the Darboux integral?

Please, avoid the use of images for central parts of your questions. Use MathJax to type the math in your posts.

Sounds like your definition of the Riemann integral is incorrect. Yes, what you linked is the definition of the Darboux integral. The Riemann integral uses function values at arbitrary points in the subintervals.

Your screenshot is from Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (known colloquially as "Baby Rudin"). It gives what is typically described as the Darboux integral, using $\inf$ and $\sup$ in each piece of the partition.
What is typically described as the Riemann integral is similar, but it uses arbitrary points in each piece of the partition. It is essential in general to allow arbitrary points, not just endpoints. In the continuous case it does not matter.
The two definitions are equivalent in the sense that a function is integrable with respect to one iff it is integrable with respect to the other, and the values of the integrals so defined are equal. Thus it does not make a mathematical difference which you choose to call the "Riemann integral."
The Riemann integral was introduced by Riemann in his Habilitationsschrift in 1854, when Darboux was 12 years old. Darboux's later version is seen as somewhat cleaner technically.
While Baby Rudin defines the "Riemann integral" using the Darboux integral definition, he basically proves the equivalence of the two definitions in Theorem 6.7 a few pages later. I tend to think this whole discussion is making a mountain out of a molehill, and perhaps that's why Rudin didn't come out and say it. For someone sufficiently expert in real analysis, the distinction is very minor, and it's obvious they'll be the same.

The definition in the linked image is definitely that of a Darboux integral. However, Darboux and Riemann integrals are entirely equivalent. Unlike, say, Lebesgue integrals, which are different from both of them.
